# How to access values in ordereddict?

Tags: csv, ordereddict

I opened and read csv file from argv to dictionary

```
data = open(argv[1])
reader = csv.DictReader(data)
dict_list = []
for line in reader:
    dict_list.append(line)
```

and now when I want to access the content of the csv file like this:

```
for x in dict_list[0]:
    print(x)
```

All I get is this:

```
"OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')])"
```

With this function:

```
for x in dict_list[0]:
    print(x)
```

I get this result:

```
name
AGATC
AATG
TATC
```

Can you help me to access 'Alice', '2', '8' and '3'.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the dictionary a couple ways.

let's initialize the dictionary with your values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dict_list = OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')])
```

which gets us:

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')])
```

you can then iterate through each key and then query the value attached:

```
for k in dict_list:
    print(f"key={k}, value={dict_list[k]}")
```

and you will get:

```
key=name, value=Alice
key=AGATC, value=2
key=AATG, value=8
key=TATC, value=3
```

or, you can get both the key and the value at the same time:

```
for (k, v) in dict_list.items():
    print(f"key={k}, value={v}")
```

which will get you the same output:

```
key=name, value=Alice
key=AGATC, value=2
key=AATG, value=8
key=TATC, value=3
```

Comment: When I do it I get this errors:    <<TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not collections.OrderedDict>>   and  <<AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'>>.

Comment: on which part? can you post the exact code that triggers the error?

Comment: Turned out dict_list OrderedDict wasn't a dictionary (it was a list, that is why the printed dict_list was  in [ ] square brackets ), so it had not 'items' attribute. I converted it to a dictionary and it worked.

Comment: in cases you want to just iterate through a list of (key, values), but not search by key, a list of tuple may be better; it depends on your use case. Don't forget to mark the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I made my  OrderedDict dict_list a dictionary and now I can access to the values of keys:

```
for x in dict_list:
    temp  = dict(x)
    for y in types_count:
        print(temp.get(y))
```